# Different validation JSON responses in Spring Data REST

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-rest, spring-validator

I'm using Spring Boot, Spring Data REST, Hibernate, JPA.
I'm experiencing a strange issue, probably due to a wrong configuration.

I'm posting relevant parts of my configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class RestConfig extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private Validator validator;

    public static final DateTimeFormatter ISO_FIXED_FORMAT = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")
            .withZone(ZoneId.of("Z"));

    @Bean
    public RootResourceProcessor rootResourceProcessor() {
        return new RootResourceProcessor();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver(ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver exceptionResolver) {

    }

    @Override
    public void configureValidatingRepositoryEventListener(ValidatingRepositoryEventListener validatingListener) {
        validatingListener.addValidator("beforeCreate", validator);
        validatingListener.addValidator("beforeSave", validator);
        super.configureValidatingRepositoryEventListener(validatingListener);
    }

}
```

Configuration of validator an message source:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaAuditing(auditorAwareRef = "springSecurityAuditorAware")
public class CustomConfiguration {
    @Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasenames("classpath:/i18n/messages");
    // messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    // set to true only for debugging
    messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(false);
    messageSource.setCacheSeconds((int) TimeUnit.HOURS.toSeconds(1));
    messageSource.setFallbackToSystemLocale(false);
    return messageSource;
}

/**
 * Enable Spring bean validation
 * https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#validation
 * 
 * @return
 */
@Bean   
public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {
    LocalValidatorFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
    return factoryBean;
}

@Bean
public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
    MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor = new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
    methodValidationPostProcessor.setValidator(validator());
    return methodValidationPostProcessor;
}
```

my bean:

```
 @Entity
@EntityListeners(MovementListener.class)
public class Movement extends AbstractEntity {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5073555669170105151L;


    @NotBlank
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String description;


    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    private PaymentType paymentType;

    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Direction direction;

    @Min(value = 0)
    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private BigDecimal amount = BigDecimal.ZERO;

    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Instant currencyDate = Instant.now();


    @JsonProperty(access = Access.READ_ONLY)
    @ApiModelProperty(readOnly = true)
    @NotNull(message = "{NotNull.movement.agent}")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    protected User agent;


    @JsonProperty(access = Access.READ_ONLY)
    @ApiModelProperty(readOnly = true)
    @NotNull(message = "{NotNull.movement.checkpoint}")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    protected CheckPoint checkPoint;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true)
    private Customer customer;


    @Type(type = "json")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "json")
    private String details;
```

and related listener:

```
    @Component
public class MovementListener {
    private Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();

    public static WorkSessionRepository workSessionRepository;

    @Autowired
    public void init(WorkSessionRepository workSessionRepository) {
        MovementListener.workSessionRepository = workSessionRepository;
    }


    @PrePersist
    private void onSaveOrUpdate(Movement value) {
        try {
            if (value != null && value.isNew()) {
                WorkSession workSession = workSessionRepository.findByAgentUsernameAndEndDateIsNull();
                if (workSession != null) {
                    value.agent = workSession.getAgent();
                    value.checkPoint = workSession.getCheckPoint();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error into MovementListener during @PrePersist.", e);
        }
    }

}
```

I'm exposing the persist method of this bean via Spring data REST:

```
 @Transactional
@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
public interface MovementRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Movement, Long> {
}
```

If I enable the validator both in `beforeCreate` and `beforeSave`, when I POST my entities with errors I see a well formatted `ConstraintViolationException` JSON error.

Wrong request:

```
    curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/hal+json' -d '{ \ 
   "amount": 0, \ 
   "currencyDate": "2017-10-10T20:49:57.959Z", \ 
   "description": "string", \ 
   "details": "string", \ 
   "direction": "IN", \ 
   "paymentType": "", \ 
   "version": 0 \ 
 }' 'http:/
```

then I've a well formatted reply:

```
 {
  "errors": [
    {
      "entity": "Movement",
      "property": "checkPoint",
      "invalidValue": null,
      "message": "Ogni movimento contabile deve essere associato ad un checkpoint. Ripetere lautenticazione e ripetere loperazione."
    },
    {
      "entity": "Movement",
      "property": "paymentType",
      "invalidValue": null,
      "message": "Il campo non può essere vuoto. Inserire un valore valido e ripetere loperazione."
    },
    {
      "entity": "Movement",
      "property": "agent",
      "invalidValue": null,
      "message": "Ogni movimento contabile deve essere associato ad un operatore. Ripetere lautenticazione e ripetere loperazione."
    }
  ]
}
```

**But**, because two fields of the bean are set inside the listener I created, I can't leave enabled the `beforeCreate` event and I should just leave only `beforeSave`.

If I do this, with the same request, I've this reply:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2017-10-10T21:04:39.450+0000",
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "exception": "javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException",
  "message": "Validation failed for classes [it.rebus.server.model.accounting.Movement] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]\nList of constraint violations:[\n\tConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='may not be null', propertyPath=paymentType, rootBeanClass=class it.rebus.server.model.accounting.Movement, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'}\n]",
  "path": "/api/v1/movements"
}
```

Seems Spring Data REST is not managing correclty the `ConstraintViolationException` but I don't understand why. I would need a hint to pick up the right way to solve the problem.

Comment: Just sidenote, formatting of response fields can be done also using annotation driven formatting, see https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#format-CustomFormatAnnotations